# jQuery Validation rules and messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble setting ups the rules and messages for jQuery Validation.

I'm trying to get the value from resume[zip_code], but I don't know how to write it in JQuery. I tried

```
rules: {
  resume[zip_code]: required: true
}
```

but does not work.

This is where I need to get the values from.

```
<div class='control-group'><label class='control-label'>Zip Code: </label>
  <div class='controls'>
    <input class="required" type='text' name='resume[zip_code]'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Application code

```
post '/create_resume' do
  session[:errors].clear
    @user = User.first(:email_address => session['user'])
    @resume = @user.resumes.new(params[:resume])
    @resume.save

  params[:education].each_key do |school|
    @school = @resume.educations.new(params[:education][school]
    @school.save
  end

  params[:job].each_key do |job|
    @job = @resume.jobs.new(params[:job][job])
    @job.save
  end

  params[:otherskill].each_key do |other|
    @otherskill = @resume.otherskills.new(params[:otherskill][other])
    @otherskill.save
  end

  if session[:errors].empty? === false
    erb :resume_form
  else
    session[:resume_output].clear
    erb :resume_output 
  end
end
```

jQuery

I know what the layout is but just don't know how to retrieve the values

```
$(#myForm).validate({
  rules: {
    something: key => value
  },
  messages: {
    something: "value"
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for having the `[]` in the name attribute? What is the actual problem here?

Comment: @ArunPJohny It's used to store user's input in datamapper. I'll add the code in.

Comment: what are the validation rules?

Comment: I need the rules to be required and it has to be interger or number, for the message I just need a custom message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have no idea how to write your rules since you never stated which rules you wanted.  Using only your provided HTML, this is how you'd set up rules and messages.

To demonstrate usage, I am *arbitrarily* making the field `required` with a minimum length of 5 numbers.

Edit and add your own rules accordingly.

```
$('#myForm').validate({
  rules: {
    "resume[zip_code]": {
         required: true,
         minlength: 5,
         digits: true
     }
  },
  messages: {
    "resume[zip_code]": {
         required: "this field is required",
         minlength: "this field must contain at least {0} characters",
         digits: "this field can only contain numbers"
     }
  }
});
```

You also do not need to put `class="required"` within the HTML because this rule is already specified with your jQuery `.validate()` method.

```
<input type='text' name='resume[zip_code]' />
```

**Working Demo:**

[**http://jsfiddle.net/vL7ps/**](http://jsfiddle.net/vL7ps/)

See documentation for all methods and rules:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

---

If you want to validate the field as a required US Zip Code, simply use the `zipcodeUS` rule, but you must first include the "Additional Methods" file [found here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/additional-methods.js

jQuery:

```
rules: {
  "resume[zip_code]": {
    required: true,
    zipcodeUS: true
  }
},
messages: {
  "resume[zip_code]": {
    required: "this field is required",
    zipcodeUS: "this field must contain valid US zip code"
  }
}
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/k6eLf/

Comment: Thank you, it works. I just need the quotations around the name of the rule.