# How to apply validation if input fields are empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am applying validations to all the input where values are left blank. Whenever any input is blank and user will click on save button them we add class has-error and display message in small tag.

I have written following html.

```
         <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Academic Year *</label>
                       <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="text" id="academicyearname" maxlength="4" class="form-control only-numbers">
                            <small id="year_nameHelp" class="text-danger hide">
                                 Academic Year is Required
                            </small>
                       </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group" id="dateStartsOn">
                         <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Starts On *</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <div class="input-group date">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </span>
                                <input aria-required="true" id="startson" class="form-control block-keypress" type="text" 
                                onclick="css()">
                                 <small id="start_dateHelp" class="text-danger hide">
                                        Start Date is Required
                                 </small>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" id="dateEndsOn">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ends On *</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <div class="input-group date">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </span>
                                <input aria-required="true" id="endson" class="form-control block-keypress" type="text" onclick="css()">
                                <small id="end_dateHelp" class="text-danger hide">
                                      End Date is Required
                                 </small>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     ...
                   ....
```

In jquery I am doing following validation on save button click

```
                      if((":input").val().trim() =="")
                     {
                         $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass( "has-error");
                         $("small").removeClass('hide');
                         return;
                     }  

                if(academicyearname == "")
                {
                    $("#academicyearname").closest(".form-group").addClass( "has-error");
                    $("#year_nameHelp").removeClass('hide');
                    $("#academicyearname").focus();
                }
                else if(startson == "")
                {
                    $("#startson").closest(".form-group").addClass( "has-error");
                    $("#start_dateHelp").removeClass('hide');
                }
                else if(endson == "")
                {
                    $("#endson").closest(".form-group").addClass( "has-error");
                    $("#end_dateHelp").removeClass('hide');
                }
                 ....
```

The part

```
           if((":input").val().trim() =="")
                     {
                         $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass( "has-error");
                         $("small").removeClass('hide');
                         return;
                     }
```

is not working accordingly. I mean it should be able to dynamically detect which inputs are empty and then add error class to the corresponding input where value is "".

Comment: Why not using Jquery validate plugin, which provides convenient way for validation.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179417/jquery-validation-rules-and-messages?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I understand if you want to use `javascript/jQuery` to validate the `form` to use `.trim()` but you can also add the `required` attribute to your `form` elements. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4Le7vah6/)

Comment: I should also mention you can set a required pattern for the inputs too using the `pattern` attribute. Here it a second [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4Le7vah6/1/) this is not allow empty spaces at the start of the input.

Comment: When posting questions it helps a lot if you place actual working code and markup. `...` for example is pretty invasive and adding a comment would be better.  Structure your question(s) to make them easy to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery validator js's **blank element plugin** and you can use it as follows:

```
$( "input:blank" ).css( "background-color", "#bbbbff" );
```

Have a look at below:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/blank-selector/

It also can be applied at id and class level.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
   var result = $("input:text").val().trim();
   if(result == ""){ 
   //do something
   }
```

Comment: try using $( "input:text" ) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
         var vendorError = false;
            $(".vendorForm input").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    jAlert('Required', 'empty');
                    vendorError = true;
                   var div = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));
                  // show meg logic
                  if (div.style.display !== "block") {
                    div.style.display = "block";
                  }
                    return false;
                }
            })
            if (vendorError) {
                return false;
            }
```

HTML file

```
<div id="vendorForm" class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Academic Year *</label>
                           <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="text" id="academicyearname" maxlength="4" class="form-control only-numbers">
                                <small id="year_nameHelp" class="text-danger hide">
                                     Academic Year is Required
                                </small>
                           </div>
                        </div>

                         <div class="form-group" id="dateStartsOn">
                             <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Starts On *</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <div class="input-group date">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                </span>
                                    <input  id="startson" value="" class="form-control block-keypress" type="text" 
                                    onclick="css()">
                                     <small id="start_dateHelp" class="text-danger hide">
                                            Start Date is Required
                                     </small>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" id="dateEndsOn">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ends On *</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <div class="input-group date">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                </span>
                                    <input  id="endson" value="" class="form-control block-keypress" type="text" onclick="css()">
                                    <small id="end_dateHelp" class="text-danger hide">
                                          End Date is Required
                                     </small>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         ...
                       ....
```

Comment: can u please write the above program in the example context

Comment: Please check - @ruta

Answer (score 0):

I understood and somewhat same module i also designed. You can make the use of modal and give that id to in the js and on click button you can run the function in your js file. See my html page:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <form id = "updateForm" onsubmit="return false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="left">
                        <div class="well img_height">
                            <img id="blah" src="admin_resources/images/user-icon.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="file" name="myfile" onchange="readURL(this);" id="myfile"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                                 <label for="emp_id">Employee Id:</label> 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp_id" name="employeeId" >
                        <p id="valid_msg_employee_id" class="error_message"></p>
                        <label for="fname">First Name:</label> 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" >
                        <p id="valid_msg_fname" class="error_message"></p>
                        <label for="lname">Last Name:</label> 
                        <input type="text"class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName">
                        <p id="valid_msg_lname" class="error_message"></p>
                        <label for="designation">Designation:</label> <br/> 
                        <select name="designation" id="dropdown" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Select">Select Designation</option>
                            <option value="manager">Manager</option>
                            <option value="HR">HR</option>
                            <option value="Tech Lead">Tech Lead</option>
                            <option value="QA Lead">QA Lead</option>
                            <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
                            <option value="QA-Automation">QA-Automation</option>
                            <option value="QA-Manual">QA-Manual</option>
                            <option value="Software Trainee">Software Trainee</option>
                            <option value="Sr. Software Quality Engineer">Sr. Software Quality Engineer</option>
                             <option value="SQE">SQE</option>
                             <option value="Software Quality Engineer">Software Quality Engineer</option>
                             <option value="Associate Software Engineer">Associate Software Engineer</option> 
                             <option value="QA Manager">QA Manager</option>   
                              </select>
                        <p id="valid_msg_designation" class="error_message"></p>
                        <label for="Doj">Joining Date:</label> 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="doj" name="yearOfJoining" >
                        <p id="valid_msg_year" class="error_message"></p>
                        <label for="status">Status:</label> <br/> 
                        <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
                            <option value="active">Active</option>
                            <option value="inactive">inactive</option>
                        </select>
                        <p id="valid_msg_designation" class="error_message"></p>
                        <p id="valid_msg_year" class="error_message"></p>
                        <label for="email_id">Email-id:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                        <p id="valid_msg_email" class="error_message"></p>
                        <label for="quali">Contact:</label> 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" name="mobileNo">
                        <p id="valid_msg_contact" class="error_message"></p>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="updateEmployeeDetail();" data-dismiss="modal">Update</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick = "deleteEmployee();" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and you can now add a class "erro_message which will be called on the modal:
the js file is this:

```
function employeeDetail() {

 $("#submit_emp").click(function(event) {

  var formValid = employeeDetail.formValidation();
  if (formValid) {
   var formvalue = new FormData($('#addForm')[0]);
   $.ajax({
    url: "intranet/addEmployee",
    type: "POST",
    data: formvalue,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
     $('#your-modal').modal('toggle');
     $("#header_success").empty();
     $("#header_success").append("Response");
     $("#message_success").empty();
     $("#message_success").append(response.message);
     $('#addForm').trigger("reset");
    },
    error: function(e) {
     $('#your-modal').modal('toggle');

     $("#message_success").empty();
     $("#message_success").append(e.message);
    }
   });
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 });
```

You can add many validations on this input type and can append the messge ypuwant on that particular fied:
Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is super simplistic and does NOT do the "validation" by checking for example numeric values, etc. but you wanted/asked for the selector for empty text inputs so this gives that.

```js
// put on some event, used change here:
$('input[type=text]').on('change', function() {
  // just clear all
  $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
  $("small").addClass('hide');
  // filter those empty ones
  $('input[type=text]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().trim() == "";
  }).each(function() {
    $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
    $(this).parent().find("small").removeClass('hide');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Academic Year *</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="text" id="academicyearname" maxlength="4" class="form-control only-numbers">
    <small id="year_nameHelp" class="text-danger hide">Academic Year is Required</small>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="dateStartsOn">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Starts On *</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="input-group date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>                                </span>
      <input aria-required="true" id="startson" class="form-control block-keypress" type="text" >
      <small id="start_dateHelp" class="text-danger hide">Start Date is Required</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="dateEndsOn">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ends On *</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="input-group date">
      <span class="input-group-addon">                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>                                </span>
      <input aria-required="true" id="endson" class="form-control block-keypress" type="text" >
      <small id="end_dateHelp" class="text-danger hide">End Date is Required</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```